# How to extract and manipulate data from text file in VB 2010 using string manipulation methods

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need help on extracting data from a specific text file (C:\test.txt). Text file contains student names and scores:

Alice,76,45,87,23
Ben,76,48,85,65
Julie,76,36,49,86
Monica,85,90,83,76

Given the grade structure which is: A (70-100), B(60-69),C(50-59),D(40-49),F(0-39)

Application should calculate the average score and grade received by each student
Display who received the highest mark
Display the average mark of all students in the class
List students who received grade "C"

The required methods to be used are Len, Mid and Instr 
File to be processed line by line

Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It can provably be tidied up because i just knocked it out.

To test it drop a multiline TEXTBOX (named textbox1) and a Button (named button1) on a form and click the button.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

'-> Data
'   Alice, 76, 45, 87, 23
'   Ben, 76, 48, 85, 65
'   Julie, 76, 36, 49, 86
'   Monica, 85, 90, 83, 76

'-> Variables
Dim strTextLine As String
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim chrCurrentCharacter As String
Dim strBuffer As String
Dim strResults As String
Dim booNameFound As Boolean

'-> Processing
'1  calculate the average score and grade received by each student 
Dim intIndividualAverage As Integer = 0
'2  Display who received the highest mark 
Dim intHighest As Integer = 0
Dim intTmpHighest As Integer = 0
Dim strHighest As String = ""
'3  Display the average mark of all students in the class 
Dim intGroupAverage As Integer = 0
'4  List students who received grade "C"
Dim strGradeCStudents = ""
Dim strName As String = ""

'-> Grading Rules
'   A (70-100), B(60-69),C(50-59),D(40-49),F(0-39)

'-> Open file and process data one line at a time
Try
  ' Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file
  Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("c:\temp\test.txt")

  ' Read the lines from the file until the end of the file is reached.
  Do
    strTextLine = objStreamReader.ReadLine()
    'if not eof or empty text line
    If Trim(strTextLine) <> "" Then
      'reset vars
      strName = ""
      strBuffer = ""
      strResults = ""
      booNameFound = False
      intIndividualAverage = 0
      For intCounter = 1 To Len(strTextLine)
        chrCurrentCharacter = Mid(strTextLine, intCounter, 1)
        'is this a comma?
        If chrCurrentCharacter = "," Then
          'has the name been found?
          If booNameFound Then
            'this is a grade result(note there is no Grade E!)
            Select Case Val(strBuffer)
              Case 70 To 100
                strResults = strResults & " A"
                intIndividualAverage = intIndividualAverage + Val(strBuffer)
                intGroupAverage = intGroupAverage + Val(strBuffer)
              Case 60 To 69
                strResults = strResults & " B"
                intIndividualAverage = intIndividualAverage + Val(strBuffer)
                intGroupAverage = intGroupAverage + Val(strBuffer)
              Case 50 To 59
                strResults = strResults & " C"
                intIndividualAverage = intIndividualAverage + Val(strBuffer)
                intGroupAverage = intGroupAverage + Val(strBuffer)
                'grade C Students
                If InStr(strGradeCStudents, strName) > 0 Then
                  'alreadylisted inthe grade c list
                Else
                  strGradeCStudents = strGradeCStudents & strName & " "
                End If
              Case 40 To 49
                strResults = strResults & " D"
                intIndividualAverage = intIndividualAverage + Val(strBuffer)
                intGroupAverage = intGroupAverage + Val(strBuffer)
              Case Else
                strResults = strResults & " F"
                intIndividualAverage = intIndividualAverage + Val(strBuffer)
                intGroupAverage = intGroupAverage + Val(strBuffer)
            End Select
            strBuffer = ""
          Else
            'this is name
            booNameFound = True
            strResults = strBuffer
            strName = strBuffer
            strBuffer = ""
          End If
          'if its not a space 
        ElseIf chrCurrentCharacter <> " " Then
          strBuffer = strBuffer & chrCurrentCharacter
        Else
          'Spaces are not processed 
        End If
      Next
      'Process LAST result because there is no comma after it
      'so it must be done after the endof the line
      Select Case Val(strBuffer)
        Case 70 To 100
          strResults = strResults & " A"
          intIndividualAverage = intIndividualAverage + Val(strBuffer)
        Case 60 To 69
          strResults = strResults & " B"
          intIndividualAverage = intIndividualAverage + Val(strBuffer)
        Case 50 To 59
          strResults = strResults & " C"
          intIndividualAverage = intIndividualAverage + Val(strBuffer)
        Case 40 To 49
          strResults = strResults & " D"
          intIndividualAverage = intIndividualAverage + Val(strBuffer)
        Case Else
          strResults = strResults & " F"
          intIndividualAverage = intIndividualAverage + Val(strBuffer)
      End Select
      strBuffer = ""
      'Student average
      strResults = strResults & " (avg=" & (intIndividualAverage / 4) & ")" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
      TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & strResults
      'Console.WriteLine(strResults)
      'Highest?
      If intHighest = 0 Then
        strHighest = strName
      ElseIf intTmpHighest > intHighest Then
        strHighest = strName
      ElseIf intTmpHighest = intHighest Then
        strHighest = strHighest & " " & strName
      End If
    Else
      'The line was empty 
    End If
  Loop Until strTextLine Is Nothing
  objStreamReader.Close()
  '-> Display Summary
  TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf & "SUMMARY" & vbCrLf
  TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "Highest Marks: " & strHighest & vbCrLf
  TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "Group Average: " & ((intGroupAverage / 4) / 4) & vbCrLf
  TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "Grade C Students: " & strGradeCStudents & vbCrLf
Catch Ex As Exception
  ' Let the user know what went wrong.
  TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "The file could not be read:"
  TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & Ex.Message
  'Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:")
  'Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message)
End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Also don't forget to change the filename/path from c:\TEMP\test.txt to c:\test.txt